# Как сделать значение ''print(key + ':', info[num][key])'' и нового словаря одинаковыми?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Необходимо , чтоб в новый словарь попадали такие же значения, как и при `print(key + ':',info[num][key])`.

Что сделал не так? Помогите исправить ошибку

```
info = {1 : {'name': 'Timur', 'job': 'Teacher'},
    2 : {'name': 'Ruslan', 'job': 'Developer'},
    3 : {'name': 'Rustam', 'job': 'Tester'}}
num = int(input("Какой номер ID? :"))
print('Employee ID:', num)
print()
new_w = {}

for key in info[num]:
    print(key + ':', info[num][key])
print()
for s in info.values():
    new_w.update(**s)
print(new_w)
```

Вывод:

```
Какой номер ID? :1
Employee ID: 1

name: Timur
job: Teacher

{'name': 'Rustam', 'job': 'Tester'}
```

Comment: В info.values() физически нет ключей, это только значения словаря

Comment: Да спасибо все работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в цикле `for s in info.values():` перебираете все значения словаря `info`, подставляя их в `new_w.update(**s)`. В результате у Вас в `new_w` будет всегда значение последнего ключа `info`.

Вместо

```
for s in info.values():
    new_w.update(**s)
```

нужно использовать тогда

```
new_w.update(info[num])
```

или вообще

```
new_w = info[num]
```

Тогда код будет примерно таким:

```
info = {1 : {'name': 'Timur', 'job': 'Teacher'},
    2 : {'name': 'Ruslan', 'job': 'Developer'},
    3 : {'name': 'Rustam', 'job': 'Tester'}}
num = int(input("Какой номер ID? :"))
print('Employee ID:', num)
for key in info[num]:
    print(key + ':', info[num][key])
new_w = {}
new_w.update(info[num])
print(new_w)
```

Вывод:

```
Какой номер ID? :1
Employee ID: 1
name: Timur
job: Teacher
{'name': 'Timur', 'job': 'Teacher'}
```